# Android - Odd extra permission dialog appearing on Galaxy TAB S7 Android 11

Tags: android, permissions, dialog, galaxy, android-11

I have tested our app - which requests background GPS permission on Galaxy S21, Pixel 5, Pixel 1 and Galaxy TAB S7 - and only on the TAB S7 do I get an extra popup permission dialog, which contains duplicate selections and our app always crashes inside Android after any selection. See attached image of dialog.

Has anyone else seen this odd permission dialog and have any clue how to prevent it from appearing and/or crashing ?

Our app requests this permission

> Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

And as state before - works perfectly on ALL mobile devices except Galaxy TAB S7 (Android 11).

Crash Trace -

> Process: com.google.android.permissioncontroller, PID: 17409
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
> at com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.logGrantPermissionActivityButtons(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:1283)
> at com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.onPermissionGrantResult(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:1039)
> at com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.handheld.GrantPermissionsViewHandlerImpl.onClick(GrantPermissionsViewHandlerImpl.java:300)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
> at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16220)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
> at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)

[image]

Code sample - using older API to request permission
[Code available on GitHub](https://github.com/landenlabs/demo-permissions)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_GPS = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_BG_LOC = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_GPS =
            {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_GPS_BG =
            {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION };
    private View mLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.sample_main_layout);
        mLayout.findViewById(R.id.get_gps_permission).setOnClickListener(this);
        mLayout.findViewById(R.id.get_bg_permission).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void getGpsPermission() {
        if (hasPerm( PERMISSIONS_GPS[0])) {
            showGotGpsPermission();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS_GPS, REQUEST_GPS);
        }
    }

    public void getBgLocationPermission() {
        if (hasPerm(PERMISSIONS_GPS_BG)) {
            showGotBgLocPermission();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS_GPS_BG, REQUEST_BG_LOC);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        boolean gotPerm = true;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < grantResults.length; idx++) {
            if (grantResults[idx] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Snackbar.make(mLayout, permissions[idx] + " not granted",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                gotPerm = false;
            }
        }

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GPS:
                if (gotPerm) showGotGpsPermission();
                break;
            case REQUEST_BG_LOC:
                if (gotPerm) showGotBgLocPermission();
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPerm(String ... permissions) {
        for (String perm : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,perm)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void showGotGpsPermission() {
        TextView tv = mLayout.findViewById(R.id.status_gps_permission);
        tv.setText(R.string.gps_permission_granted);
    }
    private void showGotBgLocPermission() {
        TextView tv = mLayout.findViewById(R.id.status_bg_permission);
        tv.setText(R.string.background_permission_granted);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.get_gps_permission) {
            getGpsPermission();
        } else if (id == R.id.get_bg_permission) {
            getBgLocationPermission();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Cause of issue - Don't keep activities]

Comment: *That's* the *dialog*? If so, that's a firmware bug in that particular Samsung model. If you post a [mcve] showing how you are requesting permissions, perhaps we can make some suggestions of how to request the permissions and avoid this bug.

Comment: I posted the code - 
https://github.com/landenlabs/demo-permissions

Comment: AFAIK, you should not need both `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` -- `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` alone should be sufficient. Are you sure that you need both? And, if you drop back to just requesting the one rather than both, does the dialog behave better? What you have should be fine, but this simplification should be good overall and might help with this bizarre behavior that you are seeing.

Comment: I isolated the problem - All Android 11 or 10 devices - with the Developer Option "Don't keep Activities" ENABLED  produce this new Permission Dialog and on Galaxy devices - crash.

Comment: The extra permission dialog appears on on Pixel 5, Galaxy S21, Galaxy TAB S7 when the "Don't keep activities" developer option is enabled.  But only the Galaxy devices crash.

Comment: @LanDenLabs Don't keep activities is unchecked on my Pixel 4a (Android 11) but I still have this issue

Comment: @CommonsWare it happens when app is in landscape orientation, settings are opened in portrait orientation

Comment: @LanDenLabs it happens when app is in landscape orientation, settings are opened in portrait orientation

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S10 (Android 11) doesn't have such bug. I can reproduce it on Pixel 4a 5G (Android 11)

Comment: It also can be reproduced with any Pixel Android 11 Emulators but it doesn't show such weird system dialog, it just closes app after returning from Settings: `Force finishing activity com.android.permissioncontroller/.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity`
`Force finishing activity com.example.requestbackgorundlocation/.MainActivity`